# Visualization of odometry msgs

Tags: navigation, odometry, rviz, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

my question is related to the code of odometry msgs at
http://www.ros.org/wiki/navigation/Tutorials/RobotSetup/Odom

How can I visualize a series of odometry msgs in rviz. How do I have to configure rviz to get a sequence of arrows illustrating path and velocity? If I start the small example together with rviz (fixed frame = /base_link) I see with target frame =  one stationary arrow?

Best wishes

Poseidonius

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10883/visualization-of-odometry-msgs/) by [Poseidonius](https://answers.ros.org/users/248/poseidonius/) on ROS Answers with karma: 427 on 2011-08-11

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Try setting your fixed frame to /odom or /map (if you have a map).  In my setup, you won't see any movement of the arrow when the fixed frame is set to /base_link.  I've attached a snapshot from RViz after rotating the robot through 360 degrees.  Note that this is using the latest Diamondback debian packages.  The latest Electric seems to have a bug wherein the arrow points straight down instead of horizontally.

--patrick

[odom_rviz_diamondback.png](https://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/ros/download.ros.org/downloads/se_migration/ros/13131603012477817.png)

---

Originally posted by [Pi Robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/30/pi-robot/) with karma: 4046 on 2011-08-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Poseidonius](https://answers.ros.org/users/248/poseidonius/) on 2011-08-18**:
Thanks for the ticket id ... I changed the line and enjoy correct visualization now !

**Comment by [Pi Robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/30/pi-robot/) on 2011-08-14**:
It does seem to be a bug.  I reported it here (https://code.ros.org/trac/ros-pkg/ticket/5120) and it has been confirmed by one other person (joq).

**Comment by [Poseidonius](https://answers.ros.org/users/248/poseidonius/) on 2011-08-14**:
Thanks patrik,

**Comment by [Poseidonius](https://answers.ros.org/users/248/poseidonius/) on 2011-08-14**:
Thanks patrik,

**Comment by [Poseidonius](https://answers.ros.org/users/248/poseidonius/) on 2011-08-14**:
I am using elctric and I see the odometry arrow pointing straight down. It is really a bug or do I write wrong code ?